# How to get array number with groovy script in SoapUI?

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I want to assert the value of a property in `Json` response with the use of Groovy script in `SoapUI`. I know a value for name but I need to know on which position the id is.

json response example:

```json
{  
   "names":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Ted"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"Ray"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "name":"Kev"
      }
   ]
}
```

Let's say I know that there is a name Ray, I want the position and the id (names[1].id)

Comment: Do you want to find the `id` value if the name is `Ray`?

Comment: Don't worry, added my answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script to find the same:

```groovy
import groovy.json.*
//Using the fixed json to explain how you can retrive the data
//Of couse, you can also use dynamic value that you get 
def response = '''{"names": [ { "id": 1, "name": "Ted", }, { "id": 2, "name": "Ray", }, { "id": 3, "name": "Kev", } ]}'''
//Parse the json string and get the names
def names = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response).names
//retrive the id value when name is Ray 
def rayId = names.find{it.name == 'Ray'}.id
log.info "Id of Ray is : ${rayId}"

//Another way to get both position and id
names.eachWithIndex { element, index ->
  if (element.name == 'Ray') {
    log.info "Position : $index, And Id is : ${element.id}"
  }
}
```

You can see here the output

[image]

Comment: @trans, did you get chance try?

Comment: this might throw null pointer exception in case there is no match in the comparison with "Ray"